# Facebook login name field missing

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I have a server, writtien in NodeJS and in it I'm requesting for some facebook user info given his access_token with the [fbgraph](https://github.com/criso/fbgraph) module (version 1.1.0).

`return Promise.promisify(graph.get)('me', {
    fields: 'picture,id,birthday,email,first_name,last_name,name,middle_name,link,timezone,updated_time,verified, ...
    access_token: token
  });`

The access token is sent by the client side (android).
The problem I'm facing is, that for a very small percentage of requests, the "name" field is missing in the response, although I get some other info like email, profile picture, ...

I thought that the "name" field was a part of the  [public_profile](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-public_profile) and is always provided, or can a user somehow set is as hidden?